# using cv2.norm based on cv2.fisheye.projectPoints causes (-215:Assertion failed) _src1.sameSize(_src2) in function 'norm'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, fisheye

Hi I'm working on a camera calibration code (relatively standard I'd say), now when running this code:

```py
for i in range(num_images):
    number_of_points=len(objpoints[i][0])
    if not fisheye:
      imgpoints2, _ = cv2.projectPoints(objpoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], mtx, dist)
    else:
      imgpoints2, _=cv2.fisheye.projectPoints(objpoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], K, D)
    error = cv2.norm(imgpoints[i], imgpoints2, cv2.NORM_L2)
    err_im[i]=np.sqrt(error/number_of_points)
    total_error += np.sqrt(error/number_of_points)
    gem_fout=np.sqrt(error/number_of_points)
    print(f'RMSE for frame nr {i} is {np.sqrt(error/number_of_points)} pixels')
```

which runs smoothly when fisheye=False, when however using the results for the fisheye calibration I get an error in the cv2.norm:

```
  error = cv2.norm(imgpoints[i], imgpoints2, cv2.NORM_L2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/norm.cpp:1082: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src1.sameSize(_src2) in function 'norm'
```

What puzzles me is that apparently the size of the result in `cv2.projectPoints` differs from that obtained from `cv2.fisheye.projectPoints`

Any idea how this can be solved (I'm new to python, so most likely I made some basic error.) (Python version 3.7, cv2 4.5.5 running on macOS Monterey version 12.1)

Thanks in advance

Francois

Comment: compare these arrays' `.shape` values